# Restore Whole Sticky Note on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, sticky-notes

I accidentally removed my Sticky Note on Windows 7 and now I've been trying to get it back.

I searched at `%AppData%\Microsoft\Sticky Notes\StickyNotes.snt` and could see some of the text that was in my Sticky Note. 
How can I get back all of the text? I used signs like *`*`* and *`|`* in the note, will this cause any trouble?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do this by restoring the file to a previous version, right click on the file, and restore it to the previous version available.

Comment: When I try to do this, there are no available versions to choose from.